# ExactTarget Rest API testing using Poster

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest

I am trying to test the Rest API with Poster for a simple Authentication call. I added the https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken URL and tried adding the content-type application/json to the Header tab and the clientId and clientSecret to the Parameters tab and the Content to Send tab. Both return "clientId is required error code=10002".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the wrong Content type on the Content to Send tab. Setting it in the Headers tab didn't override. So adding the clientId and clientSecret to the Content to Send tab with the Content Type of application/json returns an accessToken.